# Excel VBA: how to rewrite my long FormulaArray code with .replace

Tags: arrays, excel, replace, vba

How to rewrite my long `.FormulaArray` using `.Replace`. Please help me

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

Workbooks.Open (TextBox3.Text)

x = Split(TextBox2.Value, Application.PathSeparator)
y = Split(TextBox3.Value, Application.PathSeparator)

Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Activate

Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("z5").FormulaArray = "=iferror(INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-25])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""Diverse""),0),10),""-"")"
With Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("y5:y3263")
.FillDown
.Value = .Value
End With
```

I tried following code. result showing only as `Part2`. the program not replace formula in `Part2` and `Part3`.
    Dim FormulaPart1 As String
    Dim FormulaPart2 As String
    Dim FormulaPart3 As String
    Dim origRS As Long

```
origRS = Application.ReferenceStyle
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

FormulaPart1 = "=IFerror(""Part2"",""-"")"
FormulaPart2 = "INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,""Part3"",0),10)"
FormulaPart3 = "MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-25])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""Diverse"")"

With Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Worksheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("z5")

.FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
.Replace what:="""Part2""", replacement:=FormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart
.Replace what:="""Part3""", replacement:=FormulaPart3, lookat:=xlPart

End With
Application.ReferenceStyle = origRS
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Your formula appears to be trying to return the 10th column of a 1 column range so it isn't going to work. You could almost certainly use LOOKUP instead of this array formula though, unless you may have multiple matches and you want the first result rather than the last.

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct formula using `.Replace` funcation,

```
Dim FormulaPart1 As String
Dim FormulaPart2 As String
Dim FormulaPart3 As String
Dim origRS As Long

origRS = Application.ReferenceStyle
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(""Part2"",""-"")"
FormulaPart2 = "INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,""Part3"",10)"
FormulaPart3 = "MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-25])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""Diverse""),0)"

With     Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Worksheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("z5")

.FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
.Replace what:="""Part2""", replacement:=FormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart
.Replace what:="""Part3""", replacement:=FormulaPart3, lookat:=xlPart

End With
Application.ReferenceStyle = origRS
```